# How to prove strict conditional convergence of a series without needing to explicitly disprove absolute convergence?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Are there any easy tricks or theorems that can assist in proving strict conditional convergence of a series without needing to disprove absolute convergence?

Comment: Rearrange the series perhaps

Comment: If you have proven conditional convergence, you have ipso facto disproved absolute convergence.

Comment: @RobertIsrael I know. Most proof techniques either prove convergence (alternating test) or they prove absolute convegerence (ratio test). No techniques prove strict conditional convergence